# 6502 Assembly question: Should I have an instance of SEC for each SBC when there are multiple SBC in a string of calculations?

Tags: assembly, 6502, carryflag

According to [this website](https://www.atariarchives.org/2bml/chapter_10.php), under the "major uses" for `CLC`, it states:

> If there are to be a series of additions (multiple-byte addition), only the first `ADC` is preceded by `CLC` since the carry feature is necessary.

Under the "major uses" for `SBC` it states:

> You always `SEC` (set the carry flag) before an `SBC` operation so you can tell if you need a "borrow".

In other words for a series of consecutive `ADC` operations, you only need a `CLC` before the first, but before a series of consecutive `SBC` operations, you should have a `SEC` before each. Is this correct?

Comment: If you use the consecutive `SBC` to implement multi-byte subtraction then you must not use a `SEC` to allow the borrow (carry) to propagate. Similarly for `ADC` of course.

Answer (score 11):

> If there are to be a series of additions (multiple-byte addition), only the first ADC is preceded by CLC since the carry feature is necessary

This is written kind of misleadingly.  If you are using a series of ADC *to implement multiple-precision addition*, e.g. adding two 16-bit or 32-bit numbers, then you do want `CLC` before the first one only.  But if you have several consecutive ADC that are adding *unrelated* 8-bit numbers, then you want a CLC before each of them.  Otherwise, a carry from one addition would be propagated into an unrelated sum.

Then the case for SBC is exactly analogous.  If you are doing several unrelated 8-bit subtractions, you want to SEC before each one.  If you are using a series of SBC to implement 16-bit or 32-bit subtraction, etc, then you want SEC before the first one only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between adding and substracting numbers in 6502. So, `CLC` and `SBC` behaves the same. Clearing or setting carry flag before the next operation is completely your decision. You should also understand `CLC` can be used with substraction and `SBC` can be used with addition. For example;

```
lda #$40
clc
adc $10
sta $1000
inc $1000
```

In this example we add $10 memory address value to $40 and then increase the ending result by one. Instead we can do this.

```
lda #$40
sec
adc $10
sta $1000
```

This will give you the same result without an extra `INC` operation.

`CLC` and `SEC` use cases are very similar and has no difference like your original question. But you should not directly relate them to addition and substraction. You should always ask the question "which carry state do i need at this stage?" and if required, use `CLC` and `SEC` accordingly.